# sharepoint list metadata column update not working

Tags: sharepoint-server

Unable to update sharepoint list metadata column value.  issues is only with the update request, add item works without any issue only update requesting not updating metadata coloumn value.

```
  var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
 var listTitle = "mylist";
 var taxFieldName = "myColumn";
 var termLabel ="termm label";
 var termId = "a92b78b5-3505-45d5-abdd-b28e0b5385c5";

 var context = new SP.ClientContext(webUrl);
 var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);            
 var item = list.getItemById(301);

 //In case of multi-valued Managed Metadata field, the format of value is:
 //-1;#<termLabel1>|<termId1>;-1;#<termLabel2>|<termId2>;...-1;#<termLabelN>|<termIdN>

 var termValue = "-1" + ";#" + termLabel + "|" + termId;

 item.set_item(taxFieldName, termValue);
 item.update();

 context.load(item);
 context.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            console.log('Item has been updated: ' + item.get_id());
        }, 
        function (sender, args) {
             console.log(args.get_message());
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is tried and tested...

```
function updateMetadata(){

 var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
 var listTitle = "CustomList";
 var taxFieldName = "MyMMDField";
 var termLabel ="MyWikiTerm";
 var termId = "fb58bc5e-5ce5-41fc-9a90-7431018aa935";

 var context = new SP.ClientContext(webUrl);
 var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);            
 var item = list.getItemById(1);

           var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("MyMMDField");
            var taxField = context.castTo(field, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);
           // var termValue = new SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue();
          //  termValue.set_label("MyWikiTerm");
          //  termValue.set_termGuid("fb58bc5e-5ce5-41fc-9a90-7431018aa935");
           // termValue.set_wssId(-1);
           // taxField.setFieldValueByValue(item, termValue);
            var pairs = "-1;#MyWikiTerm|fb58bc5e-5ce5-41fc-9a90-7431018aa935;#-1;#MyWikiTerm2|1cee8427-41f1-4a2b-aff3-26c67685988e";
            var termValueCollection = new SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(context,pairs,taxField);


            taxField.setFieldValueByValueCollection(item, termValueCollection);


 //item.set_item(taxFieldName, termValue);
 item.update();

 context.load(item);
 context.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            console.log('Item has been updated: ' + item.get_id());
        }, 
        function (sender, args) {
             console.log(args.get_message());
        });

}
```

Hope this helps..Happy coding..!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your script you are missing CastTo(field) to update taxonomy field in list

```
var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("myColumn");
var taxField = context.castTo(field, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);
var termValue = "-1" + ";#" + termLabel + "|" + termId;
var terms = new SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(context,
termValue,
taxField);

taxField.setFieldValueByValueCollection(item, terms);
```

[And for reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e0b21ab-d3ea-4df2-900f-3ac70072f829/set-taxonomy-field-multiple-values?forum=appsforsharepoint)

Answer (score 0):

We can use the code below to achieve it.

```
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
var listTitle = "mylist";
var taxFieldName = "myColumn";
var termLabel ="termm label";
var termId = "a92b78b5-3505-45d5-abdd-b28e0b5385c5";

var context = new SP.ClientContext(webUrl);
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);            
var item = list.getItemById(301);
var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(taxFieldName);
var txField = context.castTo(field, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);

//In case of multi-valued Managed Metadata field, the format of value is:
//-1;#<termLabel1>|<termId1>;-1;#<termLabel2>|<termId2>;...-1;#<termLabelN>|<termIdN>

var termValue = new SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue();
termValue.set_label(termLabel);
termValue.set_termGuid(termId);
termValue.set_wssId(-1);
txField.setFieldValueByValue(item, termValue);

item.set_item(taxFieldName, termValue);

item.update();
context.load(item);
context.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {
        console.log('Item has been updated: ' + item.get_id());
    }, 
    function (sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

mange to fix the issue with below code:

```
 SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['sp.js', 'sp.taxonomy.js'], function () {
 var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
 var oList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("My list");
 self.oListItem = oList.getItemById(2);
 ctx.load(self.oListItem);

 //Load the managed metadata site column
 var taxFieldName = "TestColumn";
 var field = oList.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(taxFieldName);
 self.txField = ctx.castTo(field, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);
 ctx.load(self.txField);
 var termValue ="-1;#value1 |27548526-703d-4990-bd91-e06ad61deb49;#-1;#value2|f7e8c528-a47e-4f71-901f-38d471758fe0"
 var newTerms = new SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(ctx, termValue, self.txField);
 self.txField.setFieldValueByValueCollection(self.oListItem, newTerms);
 self.oListItem.update();
 ctx.load(self.oListItem);
 //Run query
 ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
          //Success
          console.log('Field successfully updated.');
    }, function (sender, args) {
          //Error
          console.log('An error occurred:' + args.get_message());
    });
 });
```